# Slow down the pace of read_html in R

Tags: r

I am scraping some forum posts that span over 207 pages using rvest. I am running into the following error:

Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 429.

I managed to "fix" it by manually using read_html on the first few individual pages, but this site in particular does not allow me to jump in between pages if it is done too quickly -- that is, if I visit multiple pages within 10 seconds it will tell me to wait 10 seconds before browsing again. This is probably some type of ddos protection and R is probably being told to "wait" and that is why my script is failing. Is there a way to use read_html more slowly, like make it browse one page every 5 seconds to not trigger this mechanism? My code is below:

```
url_base <- "https:// website here"

map_df(1:207, function(i) {
  
  # simple but effective progress indicator
  cat(".")
  
  pg <- read_html(sprintf(url_base, i))
  
  data.frame(text=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".text")),
             date=html_text(html_nodes(pg, "time")),
             coffee=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".coffeetyp_3sch")),
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  
}) -> posts
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `Sys.sleep(n)` to the function, where n is number of seconds.